# How to put references before appendix in rmarkdown with natbib citation package?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I want to insert **references** section before **appendix** section in my **rmarkdown** latex document. I tried to change my citation package from natbib to biblatex, but it looks too complicated for me and requires me to go through lots of modification. I was wondering if there could be a way to do so without changing too much on the current YAML header. Or is there any alternative ways to do so?

```
---
title: "Paper"   
thanks: 
author: |
  | \normalfont Joe
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    citation_package: natbib
    fig_caption: true
    fig_height: 4.5
    fig_width: 8
link-citations: yes
toc: false
bibliography: /Users/references02.bib
biblio-style: apalike    
in_header: preamble.tex
keep_tex: yes
fontsize: 11pt
linestretch: 1.3
subparagraph: true
number_sections: true
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \numberwithin{equation}{section}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{verbatim}
- \usepackage{chronosys}
- \usepackage{stackengine}
- \usepackage{booktabs, colortbl, xcolor}
- \usepackage{babel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
- \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
- \usepackage{filecontents}
- \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
- \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
- \newtheorem{algorithem}{Algorithm}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
- \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
- \newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}
- \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
- \UseRawInputEncoding
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=black,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = blue,      
     urlcolor=blue,
     }
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{flafter}
- \floatstyle{plaintop}
- \restylefloat{table}
- \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
- \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes} 
- \usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
- \creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
- \creflabelformat{figure}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{table}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{section}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{siunitx}
---


blah blah  \cite{ennis2019} \cite{worldbank2017}


\pagebreak
\begin{appendices}

blah blah
\cite{worldbank2017}

\end{appendices}
```

```
@article{ennis2019,
    author = {Ennis, Sean F and Gonzaga, Pedro and Pike, Chris},
    title = "{Inequality: A hidden cost of market power}",
    journal = {Oxford Review of Economic Policy},
    volume = {35},
    number = {3},
    pages = {518-549},
    year = {2019},
    month = {07},
    abstract = "{This paper explores the impact of competition on inequality by developing a new model to illustrate how higher profits from market power, and associated higher prices, could influence the distribution of wealth and income. We analyse data from eight OECD countriesâCanada, France, Germany, Korea, Japan, Spain, the United Kingdom, and the United States. In an average country in the sample, market power increases the wealth of the richest 10 per cent by between 12 and 21 per cent for a range of reasonable assumptions about savings behaviour, while it reduces the income of the poorest 20 per cent by 11 per cent or more. The results contribute to the economic literature on the origins of inequality, suggesting that lack of competition may be one source of economic inequality.}",
    issn = {0266-903X},
    doi = {10.1093/oxrep/grz017},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1093/oxrep/grz017},
    eprint = {https://academic.oup.com/oxrep/article-pdf/35/3/518/28929084/grz017.pdf},
}

@book{worldbank2017,
   author = "World Bank",
   title = "A Step Ahead: Competition Policy for Shared Prosperity and Inclusive Growth",
   year = "2017",
   pages = 245,
   url = "https://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/content/publication/978-1-4648-0945-3",
   doi = "https://doi.org/https://doi.org/10.1596/978-1-4648-0945-3" 
}
```

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre], one that actually has references?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I just modified my post, wondering if this is what you suggests. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: There is not a single citation in your document, thus no references are added, regardless of before or after the appendix. Also the document just stops mid-environment of `\begin{appendices}` without closing it

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, you're right. thanks. I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\AtEndDocument{}` around your appendices to make sure they come at the very end:

```
---
title: "Paper"   
thanks: 
author: |
  | \normalfont Joe
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
    citation_package: natbib
    fig_caption: true
    fig_height: 4.5
    fig_width: 8
    keep_tex: true
link-citations: yes
toc: false
bibliography: references02.bib
biblio-style: apalike    
in_header: preamble.tex
keep_tex: yes
fontsize: 11pt
linestretch: 1.3
subparagraph: true
number_sections: true
geometry: margin=1in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{amsthm}
- \numberwithin{equation}{section}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{geometry}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{verbatim}
- \usepackage{chronosys}
- \usepackage{stackengine}
- \usepackage{booktabs, colortbl, xcolor}
- \usepackage{babel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
- \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage{tabularx}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
- \usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
- \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
- \usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
- \usepackage{filecontents}
- \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
- \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
- \newtheorem{algorithem}{Algorithm}
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
- \usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
- \newenvironment{rcases}
  {\left.\begin{aligned}}
  {\end{aligned}\right\rbrace}
- \renewcommand{\refname}{References}
- \UseRawInputEncoding
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=black,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = blue,      
     urlcolor=blue,
     }
- \usepackage{subcaption}
- \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{flafter}
- \floatstyle{plaintop}
- \restylefloat{table}
- \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
- \setlength{\parskip}{0em}
- \usepackage{adjustbox}
- \usepackage[style=english]{csquotes} 
- \usepackage[nameinlink,capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
- \creflabelformat{equation}{#2\textup{(\textcolor{red}{#1})}#3}
- \creflabelformat{figure}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{table}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \creflabelformat{section}{#2\textcolor{red}{#1}#3}
- \usepackage{dcolumn}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{siunitx}
---


blah blah  \cite{ennis2019} \cite{worldbank2017}


\AtEndDocument{\pagebreak
\begin{appendices}

blah blah
\cite{worldbank2017}

\end{appendices}}
```

[image]

Comment: For me this causes the following error: `You can't use \`macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.`.  Do you know by any chance why?

Comment: @FelixJassler please ask a new question including a [mre] that replicates your problem

Comment: Ah, I figured out that knitr doesn't parse md inside macro calls (which makes sense). I would like to execute R code in my Appendix. Should I start a new question, or do you know if that's even possible?

Comment: @FelixJassler Please start a new question. More people will be able to see and help you

Comment: [Asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71799755/7669319)