# How to use 'apalike' bibliography style without using `citation_package: natbib` in bookdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I want 'apalike' bibliography style. But I can not use the `citation_package: natbib` because I have some Appendices which I want to put after the references section. To put Appendices after the Reference section, I used `<div id="refs"></div>`, which does not work with `citation_package: natbib`.

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    #citation_package: natbib
link-citations: yes
#biblio-style: apalike
bibliography: references.bib

documentclass: report
classoption: [oneside, a4paper] 
geometry: [top=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.2in]
fontsize: 12pt
mainfont: Times New Roman
---

# My reports
contents...

# References {-}

<div id="refs"></div>

# (APPENDIX) Appendix {-}
```

I searched for `apalike.csl` file on the internet, but did not find any. If I get the `.csl` file,  the problem could have been solved easily. But I only found `apalike.bst` file. I downloaded the file, and move it to my working directory, and added `biblio-style=apalike` to YAML section. Yet, it didn't work. So, in fact, my question is how to use a customized `.bst` file in `bookdown` without using `citation_package: natbib`?

Comment: funny i have almost the same problem at the same time https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=apa has many apa-styles as .csl

Comment: did you set csl: apa.csl in your yaml

Comment: https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=id%3Aapa  is this the csl you are looking for?

Comment: @user12256545, the Zotero Style Repository has many citation styles including `apa`, but not the `apalike` I want. There are some subtle differences between the two. And yes, `csl: apa.csl` in the YAML works just fine. But I need the `.csl` file for `apalike`. 
(Please upvote the question if you have the same problem)

Comment: @RaselBiswas:  you should explain what you want to modify in the `apa.csl` style.  CSL files are XML, and you could edit them online at https://editor.citationstyles.org or even by hand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put references before appendix in rmarkdown with natbib citation package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70455183/how-to-put-references-before-appendix-in-rmarkdown-with-natbib-citation-package)