# Place bibliography before Appendix when using natbib

Tags: latex, r-markdown, citations

I have the following document.

```
---
title: "What comes after the bibliography?"
bibliography: refs.bib
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{natbib}
  - \setcitestyle{numbers}
  - \setcitestyle{square}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: yes
---

# A

This document may use knitr[@pKnitr].

# References

<div id="refs"></div>

# Appendix

`1+1` evaluates in R to `r 1+1` (for more information, see [@pRmarkdown])
```

[image: Document output, References is after appendices]

I used `citation()` to create the bibtex references in `refs.bib`.

```
@InCollection{pKnitr,
  booktitle = {{Implementing Reproducible Computational Research}},
  editor = {Victoria Stodden and Friedrich Leisch and Roger D. Peng},
  title = {knitr: A Comprehensive Tool for Reproducible Research in {R}},
  author = {Yihui Xie},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  year = {2014},
  note = {ISBN 978-1466561595},
  url = {http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781466561595}
}

@Book{pRmarkdown,
  title = {{R Markdown Cookbook}},
  author = {Yihui Xie and Christophe Dervieux and Emily Riederer},
  publisher = {Chapman and Hall/CRC},
  address = {Boca Raton, Florida},
  year = {2020},
  note = {ISBN 9780367563837},
  url = {https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook}
}
```

I want to place my bibliography before the Appendix. So far I've tried the following, unfortunately with no luck.

- Add `<div id="refs"></div>` (see example above)
- Using [`\AtEndDocument{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70462625/7669319) - its contents won't transpile to LaTeX
- `\printbibliography` does not work with natbib
- [`\bibliography{refs}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331641/163196) kinda works, but I have to manually delete the bibliography macro created by md / Rmd

For the last point, if I have the following in my Rmd file...

```
<!-- ... -->
# References

\bibliography{refs}

# Appendix

`1+1` evaluates in R to `r 1+1` (for more information, see [@pRmarkdown])
```

... it produces the following LaTeX file.

```latex
% ...
\section{A}\label{a}}

This document may use knitr\citep{pKnitr}.

\hypertarget{references}{%
\section{References}\label{references}}

\bibliography{refs.bib}

\hypertarget{appendix}{%
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix}}

\texttt{1+1} evaluates in R to 2 (for more information, see
\citep{pRmarkdown})

  \bibliography{refs.bib}

\end{document}
```

So `\bibliography{refs.bib}` is now added twice, causing a `Citations multiply defined` error.

How can I add the bibliography before my Appendix using natbib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use remove all the interference from markdown, you are more flexible with the placement of the bibliography:

```
---
title: "What comes after the bibliography?"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{natbib}
  - \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  - \setcitestyle{numbers}
  - \setcitestyle{square}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: yes
---

# A

This document may use knitr \cite{pKnitr}.

\bibliography{refs}

# Appendix

`1+1` evaluates in R to `r 1+1` (for more information, see \cite{pRmarkdown})
```

[image]

Comment: Hm... do you know though, why the numbers/square citation style isn't applied here?

Comment: @FelixJassler Please see my edited answer

Comment: Ah, just the `plainnat` missing. Thank you!

Comment: @FelixJassler Na, the tricky part was removing the `bibliography: refs.bib` to stop markdown from interfering :)